# Controle de Login multiplos bancos

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Bom, tenho minha aplicação e cada cliente terá seu próprio banco de dados.
Como cada cliente terá seu banco de dados, também terá sua tabela de usuários para login.

Então tenho

BancoEmpresa1 - Usuario/Senha: Vanessa@email.com/123

BancoEmpresa2 - Usuario/Senha: Marcela@email.com/123

Então, tenho minha tela de login com os seguintes campos:

Login/Email:
Senha:

Como vou saber direcionar o banco correto para meu usuário? que ao usuário Vanessa digitar, ir para seu respectivo banco (BancoEmpresa1) e não cair em outro banco?

[Edit] Tecnologia usada: Asp.net MVC + Entity Framework

[Edit2] Cada cliente terá seu próprio banco de dados e estes ficarão hospedados no meu servidor e para poder acessar a aplicação, deverão passar por uma única tela de login que também ficará no meu servidor. Ex: `www.sitedoRod.com/apps/login` e daí então direcionar cada usuário para sua aplicação e banco de dados respectivos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sem informar em uma linguagem de programação específica, vou indicar ideias.

**1ª - Tabela MASTER de logins**

Uma ideia era ter uma tabela LOGIN que não faça parte de nenhum banco de dados, após validar se o usuário existe ou não, retornar dessa tabela de login, um campo que contenha o nome do banco de dados que esse usuário terá acesso, daí então utilizar esse nome em todas as consultas.

**2ª - Informar banco de Dados**

Na hora do login, verificar na aplicação do cliente um arquivo de configuração, contendo o nome do banco de dados que deva utilizar. (Comumente usado na `ConnectionString` ou em alguma `appSettings`)

**3ª - Verificar banco por banco [não recomendo neeeeeeeeeeeeeem um pouco, mas...]**

Na hora do login, verificar todas as bases de dados do servidor, se existir algum login, logar, se não, retornar informando que o login não é válido

Comment: Asp.net MVC com Entity Framework é o que estou usando

Comment: como falei com o Vinicius abaixo, em que momento eu iria salvar nessa tabela "login" ? Quando cada cliente for cadastrar um usuário para o sistema dele? E também em relação a segurança, teria que deixar esse meu banco aberto em todos os meus clientes?

Comment: Rod, você pretende hospedar todos os bancos de dados em um servidor seu e seu cliente acessará seu servidor? Ou você pretender ter um único banco de dados que servirá para todos os clientes? atenha-se que BANCO DE DADOS != de SERVIDOR DE BANCO DE DADOS

Comment: No seu servidor, vai ter um único banco de dados, ou cada cliente vai ter um banco de dados no seu servidor?

Comment: Servidor meu, sql server. E cada cliente terá sua base de dados

Comment: Cada Cliente terá sua aplicação no servidor seu ou no dele, ou terá algo como `www.sitedoRod.com/login` para o cliente acessar a aplicação dele?

Comment: será no meu, como você citou www.sitedorod.com/login é única tela de login para todos os meus clientes

Comment: Então você terá que fazer a tabela Master, e na hora do login como citado pelo @Vinicius cadastrar também nessa tabela Master os dados de Usuario/Email,Senha,Banco e guardar essa informação de Banco sempre em uma Session por exemplo e utilizar ela em todas as suas consultas para construir a queryString da conexão com o banco

Comment: Pensei em deixar o login, e o caminho do banco, ao verificar o login, conectar no banco e conferir lá a senha...o que acha? aí não deixo a senha dele nessa tabela "master"

Comment: Pode ser, mas aí entra um outro problema que é a possibilidade de existir logins duplicados por exemplo `username: joao.joazinho banco:emp1` e `username:joao.joaozinho banco:emp2` e serem dois usuários distintos... daí você terá q usar realmente algo único para garantir que não ocorra isso

Comment: mas e se for por email?

Comment: email pode ser usado, e até evita esse tipo de problema, eu só quis ressaltar algo que pudesse vir causar problema caso quisesse um `username` no lugar de um `email`

Comment: Entendi, acho que foi valida sua resposta, agora vou ter que testar e ver se não acontecerá erros nisso, rsrrs, obrigado